# verizon router port forwarding

Tags: router, webserver, ddns, noip

I have a residential verizon connection with gateway router (no static ip).
I have a windows server 2012 with IIS and need to access this from outside.
I setup a noip (ddns) account and configured it in my router dynamic dns configuration with login/pwd for the host (xxxxx.ddns.net). I installed the DU client from noip which runs in the background. My public ip is 74.xx.xx.xx
But I couldnt access xxxxx.ddns.net from outside.

I did a ipconfig on my command line and used that local ip (ip4) (192.x.x.252) in my router port forwarding with 80, 443 as port. I tried different port numbers as well.

But when I checked with http://www.portchecktool.com, the ip is 74.xx.xx.xx and when i entered 80 for port. it is not working for different port number as well. Says "Not Open"

Not sure how to connect iis web server to connect to xxxxx.ddns.net using my verizon residential service with no static ip.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Venky

Comment: It does not appear your router supports port forwarding.

Comment: It has port forwarding in router configuration.https://www.verizon.com/support/residential/quick-guides/port-forwarding.htm

Comment: Have you tried switching the port to something other then 80/443 because most iSPs like Verizon will block those ports preventing people from running home servers.

Comment: Yes I did with different port numbers like 5555, 8080

Answer (score -1):

I was adding the wrong IP. I fixed this and has the port forward to 80. It worked. Thanks